# Import of .dmp file not happening

Tags: oracle, impdp

I have created a Directory D44

```
CREATE DIRECTORY D44 AS 'C:/Users/Siddharth/Oracle_dump_files';
```

and given it access through another user using this command

```
grant read,write on directory D44 to FINANCE9;
```

But now when I am trying to import .dmp files along with the log files it is throwing the below errors

Command used and erros:

```
C:\Users\Siddharth>impdp FINANCE9/FIN123 schemas=FINANCEV1 directory=D44 dumpfile=APD_FY23_Q1_FINAL.DMP REMAP_SCHEMA=FINANCEV1:FINANCE9 logfile=APD_FY23_Q1_FINAL.log

Import: Release 12.2.0.1.0 - Production on Mon Feb 27 17:12:23 2023

Copyright (c) 1982, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
ORA-39002: invalid operation
ORA-39070: Unable to open the log file.
ORA-29283: invalid file operation
ORA-29283: invalid file operation
```

Please help me in reading the .dmp files

Comment: IMPDP is a command-line tool. As you're running it on MS Windows and directory (Oracle object) is set to "C:/Users/Siddharth", are you currently logged in (to Windows) as Siddharth? Because, if you are not, Windows won't let you write into directory owned by another operating system user. Also, did you check whether GRANT you ran succeeded?

Comment: I am currently in my system "C:/Users/Siddharth" and I have given grant access from another local user FINANCE10 which I have created 
: grant read,write on directory D44 to FINANCE9;

Comment: Maybe you didn't understand what I asked; it is not whether you (on Command prompt) went to that directory (using the CD command), but whether user who is currently logged into Windows really is Siddharth. Is it? As of GRANT: directory is (usually) created by user named SYS; it also grants privileges. You said that you did it connected as FINANCE10. What kind of user is FINANCE10? Does it have any special role (DBA? something else)?

Comment: The Windows directory must be readable and writable by the user running the Oracle database - e.g. `oracle` or `SYSTEM` - not necessarily the user executing impdp from the command line. The Oracle database user must have read/write access to the directory object in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing an export of a table for that user to check that the directory was created correctly, in my opinion, you are writing the directory wrong using slashes instead of backslashes, but since I don't work with oracle on windows I can't be sure.